# Different output when executing from cmd and Codeblocks

Tags: c++, boost, cmd, codeblocks, boost-filesystem

The following program gives different results when executed from CodeBlocks and from cmd -:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#define BOOST_FILESYSTEM_NO_DEPRECATED
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace boost::filesystem;

int main()
{
    // A valid existing folder path on my system.
    // This is actually the path containing the program's exe.
    path source = "D:\\anmol\\coding\\c++\\boost\\boost1\\bin\\release";

    cout << "output =  " << equivalent( source, "D:" ) << " !!!\n";
    return 0;
}
```

The output from CodeBlocks after running it from inside the IDE -:

```
output = 0 !!!
```

The output from cmd by executing `boost1` after changing the current directory to the folder containing the executable ( the `source` path mentioned in the code ) -:

```
output = 1 !!!
```

According to me, the output given by CodeBlocks should be the correct one.

I am running this program on Windows 7 SP1 64-bit and CodeBlocks 13.12.
I am using TDM-GCC 4.9.2 (32-bit) and Boost 1.57 to build this program.

The wrong output from cmd comes only if I execute the program after changing the current directory to the folder containing the executable.
If I keep the cmd's current directory to some other folder, the correct output is displayed.

**EDIT -:**

The original problem I was trying to solve was to check whether a file/directory was a descendant of another directory or not.
For accomplishing that, I implemented the following code -:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#define BOOST_FILESYSTEM_NO_DEPRECATED
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace boost::filesystem;

// Returns the difference in height in the filesystem tree, between the directory "parent" and the file/folder "descendant"
static int HeightDiff( const path parent, path descendant )
{
    int diff = 0;
    while ( !equivalent( descendant, parent ) )
    {
        descendant = descendant.parent_path();
        if ( descendant.empty() )
        {
            diff = -1;  // "descendant" is not a descendant of "parent"
            break;
        }
        diff++;
    }
    return diff;
}

// Returns true if the file/folder "descendant" is a descendant of the directory "parent"
static bool IsDescendant( const path parent, path descendant )
{
    return HeightDiff( parent, descendant ) >= 1;
}

int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
    if ( isDescendant( canonical( argv[1] ), canonical( argv[2] ) ) )
    {
        cerr << "The destination path cannot be a descendant of the source path!! Please provide an alternate destination path !!" << endl;
    }
}
```

Now, if I executed the code with `argv[1]="D:\anmol\coding\c++\boost\boost1\bin\release"` and `argv[2]="D:\anmol\coding\c++\boost\boost1\bin"`, it would return `true`, when it should have returned `false` instead. (Since, in this case, the `parent` is actually the descendant of `descendant`)

The reason for this is that during the while loop in `HeightDiff()`, after some iterations, `descendant` would take the value `D:`. Consequently, `equivalent()` will return true and stop the loop one step before `descendant` becomes an empty string.

I did not know earlier that `D:` refers to the current directory, and hence asked this question.

Is there any way to modify the `HeightDiff` function so that it gives the correct output ?

Will replacing the `equivalent()` condition with `while(descendant != parent)` give correct output on all the cases ?

If not, then is there any other solution ?

Comment: it seems that CodeBlocks doesn't set the current directory where the binary is. Try to use `GetCurrentDirectory` win32 function, to check where the current dir is set.

Comment: The current directory which CodeBlocks sets is  - `D:\anmol\coding\c++\boost\boost1`, probably because its the project's main directory. Anyway, since I am entering the full path inside my code, why should it matter what the current directory is ?

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve with your program? The current directory matters because D: (without a slash in the end) resolves to the current directory on drive D. So equivalent() returns true if "source" contains the current directory on drive D: .

Comment: @durkmurder why would you use the win32 function? OP is using Boost Filesystem already http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/filesystem/doc/reference.html#current_path

Comment: @SergeRogatch Edited the question to provide context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After replacing the `equivalent` condition with `while(descendant != parent)`, the program is working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Just replace

```
equivalent( source, "D:" )
```

with

```
equivalent( source, "D:\\" )
```

and you should get the expected results: the slash after `D:` (as suggested by Serge Rogatch) will make the string refer to the root directory.

Comment: This does not answer my question.